# Using many-to-many nested models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got the following situation setup to model a Customer with multiple addresses and a reference table for the type of address.  The data model is 
Customer - Address :  many to many relationship, represented with a join table called 'Location'.
LocationType - Location : one to many, so that a locationtype (eg 'work', 'home') can have many associations to a Location.

What i'm trying to achieve is the ability to simply locate all the 'work' addresses for a customer, or the 'delivery' addresses.  Whilst avoiding having the text duplicated in the join table Location

The model(s) look like:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations  
  has_many :customers, :through => :locations  
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base  
   has_many :locations  
   has_many :addresses, :through => :locations do  
   def special_location(loc)  
       find :all, :conditions => ['addr_type == ?', loc]  
   end  
  end  
end 

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :address
    belongs_to :customer
    belongs_to :locationtype
end

class LocationType < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :locations
end
```

This works ok for the simple cases of :

```
@customer = Customer.find(1)  
@customer.addresses   # return all addresses
```

And with the 'special helper method' of special_location("string") I can achieve the result.  What I wanted to find out is how I could achieve the same via the use of the additional reference table (LocationType)
Something along the lines of

```
@customer.addresses.find_locationtype("work")
```

Comment: I overlooked the one-to-many relationship of Addresses to Locations. Damien MATHIEU's solution is closer to what needs to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some tables to be joined in the select request.

```
def find_locationtype(type)
    find :all, :conditions => ['location_types.name = ?', type], :joins => :location, :locationtype
end
```

When you do `customer.find_locationtype('work')`, the generated query will join the tables `location` and `locationtype`. So you'll have access to every field from these two tables and be able to add conditions on them.

Comment: Is this method added to the model or the controller ?  It makes sense to have it on the model, as that is the source of information being requested